# How to hide softkeyboad when activity start in android?

Tags: android, layout, button, keyboard, android-edittext

I have android app in which one layout contains `Linearlayout`, `ScrollView`, `TextView`, `EditView` and `Button`. when I call from one activity to other this activity call and set `layout` which I have describe.

I would like to know when activity call there is by default `EditView` selected. and open the `softkeyboard`. I don't want to open that keyboard when activity start. but I want to open that `softkeyboard` on touch event of `EditView`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

More details about `windowSoftInputMode` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

This setting will hide soft keyboard when user enters new Activity (even if EditText control gains the focus). Soft keyboard will be shown only when user clicks the edit box control.

Comment: As a follow-up that might be useful for some, you can also do the following (in the event you were already using another `android:windowSoftInputMode`:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"`

Answer (score 1):

You can hide keyboard by add two lines to the parent view of editText.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```