# Soft Keyboard disable

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

My keyboard automatically open when I go to new activity having EditText in it. I have to disable this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity?rq=1

Comment: you need to stop the auto focusing of edittext, by making some other layout elements auto focusable. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide softkeyboad when activity start in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990966/how-to-hide-softkeyboad-when-activity-start-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use windowSoftInputMode for disable your keyboard.

```
<activity
   android:name="YourActivituy"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: great you can use easily for all activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this with your activity which contain editText :

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Activity `onCreate()` method where you want to hide the Keyboard

```
  this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this in AndroidManifest.xml

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`

2. Or you can use this on EditText,Shift the focus to the TextView,
   Calling the TextView requestFocus() in the Activity.

`android:focusable="true"`
`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`